# Cannot send SMTP mail from AWS EC2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to send an email using SMTP. 
It works fine in my local. But it does not work when i built it on AWS EC2 server.

This is my code to config and send email!
Any idea for me?

```
try{

     Properties props = System.getProperties();
     props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",true);
     props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
     props.put("mail.smtp.user","test@gmail.com");
     props.put("mail.smtp.password","testpassword");
     props.put("mail.smtp.port","587");
     props.put("mail.smtp.auth",true);
     props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");

     String[] to = {toEmail};

     Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("test@gmail.com"));
     InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

        // To get the array of addresses
        for( int i=0; i < to.length; i++ ) { // changed from a while loop
            toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("EMAIL TO:"+toEmail);

        for( int i=0; i < toAddress.length; i++) { // changed from a while loop
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
        }
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(content);
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com","test@gmail.com","testpassword");
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
  }
  catch(Exception ex){
         log.debug("send Email failed", ex);
  }
```

Comment: did you try to `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` from the EC2 instance?  this would check if the connection to the server on that port is open

Comment: check whether the Ec2 is in a public subnet or any Nat gateway is attached. Can you please share the exact exception you got.

Answer (score 3):

AWS EC2 does not allow normal use of port 25 - the SMTP port.

It is severely throttled.

If you make very very light use of it then you might see sending email off the AWS account working occassionally.  But generally it is not reliable

To resolve this problem there are two options

1. use AWS SES simple email service.  Or SNS for some really simple use cases
2. ask AWS support to remove the restriction https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request

Comment: AWS has this issue documented in their knowledge base: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/

Answer (score 2):

We were recently bit by this issue as well. AWS by default throttles the number of connections that can originate from ec2 instances. The limitation is part of the EC2 service itself. Ironically it doesn't show any mention of this as a "limit" under the limits section of the EC2 service. It is mentioned on the form though to have this limit removed from your account:

> I'm having trouble sending email over port 25 of my Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance, or I'm getting frequent timeout errors. How do I remove the port 25 throttle on my EC2 instance?

It's also mentioned on the AWS Service Limits page for EC2:

[image: ss#1]

The removal can be done in minutes once you submit the form to AWS.

#### References

- [How do I remove the throttle on port 25 from my EC2 instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/)
- [Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_ec2)